# Dynamically set property of nested object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have an object that could be any number of levels deep and could have any existing properties.
For example:

```js
var obj = {
    db: {
        mongodb: {
            host: 'localhost'
        }
    }
};
```

On that I would like to set (or overwrite) properties like so:

```js
set('db.mongodb.user', 'root');
// or:
set('foo.bar', 'baz');
```

Where the property string can have any depth, and the value can be any type/thing.
Objects and arrays as values don't need to be merged, should the property key already exist.

Previous example would produce following object:

```js
var obj = {
    db: {
        mongodb: {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root'
        }
    },
    foo: {
        bar: baz
    }
};
```

How can I realize such a function?

Comment: What should be the result for `set('foo', 'bar'); set('foo.baz', 'qux');`, where `foo` first holds a `String` then becomes an `Object`? What happens to `'bar'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: could posible this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/how-do-i-add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Comment: If you remove the `set()` method and just do `obj.db.mongodb.user = 'root';` you'd have exactly what you seem to be wanting ?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Lonowski `bar` gets overwritten by the `Object`.
@adeneo and @rmertins Indeed :) But I have to wrap some other logic around unfortunately.
@Robert Levy I found that one and got the accessing working, but setting it seems so much more complicated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: how to dynamically create nested objects using object names given by an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484673/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-using-object-names-given-by)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This function, using the arguments you specified, should add/update the data in the `obj` container.  Note that you need to keep track of which elements in `obj` schema are containers and which are values (strings, ints, etc.) otherwise you will start throwing exceptions.

```
obj = {};  // global object

function set(path, value) {
    var schema = obj;  // a moving reference to internal objects within obj
    var pList = path.split('.');
    var len = pList.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
        var elem = pList[i];
        if( !schema[elem] ) schema[elem] = {}
        schema = schema[elem];
    }

    schema[pList[len-1]] = value;
}

set('mongo.db.user', 'root');
```

Comment: @bpmason1 could you explain why you used `var schema = obj` instead of just `obj` everywhere?

Comment: @sman591 `schema` is a pointer which gets moved down the path with `schema = schema[elem]`. So after the for loop, `schema[pList[len - 1]]` points to mongo.db.user in `obj`.

Comment: that solved my problem thanks, couldn't find this in MDN docs.  But i have another doubt, if assignment operator gives a reference to the internal objects then how to make a separate object2 from the object1 so that changes done on object2 will not reflect on the object1.

Comment: @Onix You can make use of lodash `cloneDeep` function for this.

Comment: @Onix const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))

Comment: @Onix that will never happen. only when you change props that happens

Comment: how can we add an array value as a nested element? @bpmason1

Answer (score 128):

Lodash has a [_.set()](https://lodash.com/docs#set) method.

```
_.set(obj, 'db.mongodb.user', 'root');
_.set(obj, 'foo.bar', 'baz');
```

Comment: Can it be used to set the value for key as well? if yes can you share an example. Thank you

Comment: This is great, but how would you keep track of / determine the path ?

Comment: @aheuermann I've several levels of nested array how can I set the property in case of multilevel nested array of objects

Comment: lodash set also accepts an array for the path, e.g. `_.set(obj, ['db', 'mongodb', 'user'], 'root');`

Comment: Be aware that this will not work as expected when part of key contains number like 'foo.bar.350350'. It will instead create 350350 empty elements!

Comment: how do you make lodash not create an array but string always even when it's numbers?

Comment: Therefore you need to install lodash in your project. I would prefer a vanilla JS solution like the one from bpmason1

Comment: Add lodash solutions when they ask for lodash solution!!

Answer (score 31):

I just write a small function using ES6 + recursion to achieve the goal.

```
updateObjProp = (obj, value, propPath) => {
    const [head, ...rest] = propPath.split('.');

    !rest.length
        ? obj[head] = value
        : this.updateObjProp(obj[head], value, rest.join('.'));
}

const user = {profile: {name: 'foo'}};
updateObjProp(user, 'fooChanged', 'profile.name');
```

I used it a lot on react to update state, it worked pretty well for me.

Comment: this was handy, i had to put a toString() on proPath to make it work with nested properties, but after that it worked great. const [head, ...rest] = propPath.toString().split('.');

Comment: @user738048 @Bruno-Joaquim the line `this.updateStateProp(obj[head], value, rest);` should be `this.updateStateProp(obj[head], value, rest.join());`

Answer (score 25):

A bit late but here's a non-library, simpler answer:

```
/**
 * Dynamically sets a deeply nested value in an object.
 * Optionally "bores" a path to it if its undefined.
 * @function
 * @param {!object} obj  - The object which contains the value you want to change/set.
 * @param {!array} path  - The array representation of path to the value you want to change/set.
 * @param {!mixed} value - The value you want to set it to.
 * @param {boolean} setrecursively - If true, will set value of non-existing path as well.
 */
function setDeep(obj, path, value, setrecursively = false) {
    path.reduce((a, b, level) => {
        if (setrecursively && typeof a[b] === "undefined" && level !== path.length){
            a[b] = {};
            return a[b];
        }

        if (level === path.length){
            a[b] = value;
            return value;
        } 
        return a[b];
    }, obj);
}
```

This function I made can do exactly what you need and a little more.

lets say we want to change the target value that is deeply nested in this object:

```
let myObj = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
           target: 1
       }
    }
}
```

So we would call our function like so:

```
setDeep(myObj, ["level1", "level2", "target1"], 3);
```

will result in:

myObj = {
        level1: {
            level2: {
               target: 3
           }
        }
    }

Setting the set recursively flag to true will set objects if they don't exist.

```
setDeep(myObj, ["new", "path", "target"], 3, true);
```

will result in this:

```
obj = myObj = {
    new: {
         path: {
             target: 3
         }
    },
    level1: {
        level2: {
           target: 3
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Used this code, clean and simple.  
Instead of computing `level` I used `reduce`'s third argument.

Comment: I believe that `level` needs to be +1 or `path.length` -1

Comment: you shouldn't use reduce when not performing a reduction.

Comment: @McTrafik what should you use instead

Comment: A loop. The reduce function is just sugar syntax for a for-loop with an accumulator applicable for a reduction. See something like this: https://medium.com/winnintech/implementing-reduce-in-javascript-part-1-7ea8711e194 and this code DOES NOT accumulate anything nor does it perform a reduction so the reduce call here is a misuse of the pattern.

Comment: but the value does accumulate as it traverses through deeply nested values. I don't think using reduce is a bad idea. Besides, this code also sets the non-existing values. I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: `reduce` should not be used with side effects (intended as a pure function). A good rule of thumb is that if the return of `map`, `filter`, or `reduce` is not used, the function itself should be replaced with `forEach`.

Answer (score 23):

We can use a recursion function:

```
/**
 * Sets a value of nested key string descriptor inside a Object.
 * It changes the passed object.
 * Ex:
 *    let obj = {a: {b:{c:'initial'}}}
 *    setNestedKey(obj, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'changed-value')
 *    assert(obj === {a: {b:{c:'changed-value'}}})
 *
 * @param {[Object]} obj   Object to set the nested key
 * @param {[Array]} path  An array to describe the path(Ex: ['a', 'b', 'c'])
 * @param {[Object]} value Any value
 */
export const setNestedKey = (obj, path, value) => {
  if (path.length === 1) {
    obj[path] = value
    return
  }
  return setNestedKey(obj[path[0]], path.slice(1), value)
}
```

It's more simple!

Comment: looks good! just needs to check the obj param to make sure its not falsey, will throw an error if any of the props down the chain dont exist.

Comment: you can just use path.slice(1);

Comment: Excellent answer, a nice and concise solution.

Comment: I believe in that if statement, it should have been `obj[path[0]] = value;` because `path` is always of type `string[]`, even when there is only 1 string left.

Comment: Javascript objects should work using `obj[['a']] = 'new value'`. Check the code: https://jsfiddle.net/upsdne03/

Comment: just need to add -> if(!obj) return

Comment: This assumes that the nested key already exists.

Answer (score 12):

Inspired by @bpmason1's answer:

```js
function leaf(obj, path, value) {
  const pList = path.split('.');
  const key = pList.pop();
  const pointer = pList.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (accumulator[currentValue] === undefined) accumulator[currentValue] = {};
    return accumulator[currentValue];
  }, obj);
  pointer[key] = value;
  return obj;
}

const obj = {
  boats: {
    m1: 'lady blue'
  }
};
leaf(obj, 'boats.m1', 'lady blue II');
leaf(obj, 'boats.m2', 'lady bird');
console.log(obj); // { boats: { m1: 'lady blue II', m2: 'lady bird' } }
```

Comment: This doesn't take care of array indices like @bpmason1's

Answer (score 11):

I came up with my own solution using pure es6 and recursion that doesn't mutate the original object.

```js
const setNestedProp = (obj = {}, [first, ...rest] , value) => ({
  ...obj,
  [first]: rest.length
    ? setNestedProp(obj[first], rest, value)
    : value
});

const result = setNestedProp({}, ["first", "second", "a"], 
"foo");
const result2 = setNestedProp(result, ["first", "second", "b"], "bar");

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: You can eliminate the first if block by declaring "obj" with a default value setNestedProp = (obj = {}, keys, value) => {

Comment: Yh nice. Looking back could destructure the keys argument in situ too and save another line of code

Comment: Basically a one liner now 

Answer (score 10):

ES6 has a pretty cool way to do this too using *Computed Property Name* and *Rest Parameter*.

```
const obj = {
  levelOne: {
    levelTwo: {
      levelThree: "Set this one!"
    }
  }
}

const updatedObj = {
  ...obj,
  levelOne: {
    ...obj.levelOne,
    levelTwo: {
      ...obj.levelOne.levelTwo,
      levelThree: "I am now updated!"
    }
  }
}
```

If `levelThree` is a dynamic property i.e. to set any of the property in `levelTwo`, you can use `[propertyName]: "I am now updated!"` where `propertyName` holds the name of the property in `levelTwo`.

Answer (score 9):

Lodash has a method called [update](https://lodash.com/docs#update) that does exactly what you need.

This method receives the following parameters:

1. The object to update
2. The path of the property to update (the property can be deeply nested)
3. A function that returns the value to update (given the original value as a parameter)

In your example it would look like this:

```
_.update(obj, 'db.mongodb.user', function(originalValue) {
  return 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to achieve the same thing, but in Node.js...
So, I found this nice module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nested-property

Example:

```
var mod = require("nested-property");
var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: 5
      }
    }
  }
};
console.log(mod.get(obj, "a.b.c.d"));
mod.set(obj, "a.b.c.d", 6);
console.log(mod.get(obj, "a.b.c.d"));
```

Comment: how to solve for complex nested objects.
```
const x = {
    'one': 1, 
    'two': 2, 
    'three': {
        'one': 1, 
        'two': 2, 
        'three': [
            {
                'one': 1
            },
            {
                'one': 'ONE'
            },
            {
                'one': 'I'
            }
        ]
    },
    'four': [0, 1, 2]
};

console.log(np.get(x, 'three.three[0].one')); 
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using ES 12

```js
function set(obj = {}, key, val) {
  const keys = key.split('.')
  const last = keys.pop()
  keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, obj)[last] = val
}
```

(For older versions of javascript, you can do do `o[k] || o[k] = {}` in the reduce instead)

First, we set `keys` to be an array of everything but the last key.

Then in the reduce, the accumulator goes one level deeper into `obj`
each time, initializing it to an empty object if it the value at that key is not defined.

Finally, we set the value at the last key to `val`.

Answer (score 2):

I created [gist](https://gist.github.com/Chiff/5ceba1081bbf0162b98860b34a511a92) for setting and getting obj values by string based on correct answer. You can download it or use it as npm/yarn package.

```
// yarn add gist:5ceba1081bbf0162b98860b34a511a92
// npm install gist:5ceba1081bbf0162b98860b34a511a92
export const DeepObject = {
  set: setDeep,
  get: getDeep
};

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621
function getDeep(obj: Object, path: string) {
  path = path.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
  path = path.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
  const a = path.split('.');
  for (let i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; ++i) {
    const n = a[i];
    if (n in obj) {
      obj = obj[n];
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }

  return obj;
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937118
function setDeep(obj: Object, path: string, value: any) {
  let schema = obj;  // a moving reference to internal objects within obj
  const pList = path.split('.');
  const len = pList.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    const elem = pList[i];
    if (!schema[elem]) {
      schema[elem] = {};
    }
    schema = schema[elem];
  }

  schema[pList[len - 1]] = value;
}

// Usage
// import {DeepObject} from 'somePath'
//
// const obj = {
//   a: 4,
//   b: {
//     c: {
//       d: 2
//     }
//   }
// };
//
// DeepObject.set(obj, 'b.c.d', 10); // sets obj.b.c.d to 10
// console.log(DeepObject.get(obj, 'b.c.d')); // returns 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending the accepted answer provided by [@bpmason1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2736119/bpmason1), to support arrays in string path e.g. string path can be `'db.mongodb.users[0].name'` and `'db.mongodb.users[1].name'`.

It will set the property value, which if doesn't exist, will be created.

```js
var obj = {};

function set(path, value) {
  var schema = obj;
  var keysList = path.split('.');
  var len = keysList.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    var key = keysList[i];
    // checking if key represents an array element e.g. users[0]
    if (key.includes('[')) {
      //getting propertyName 'users' form key 'users[0]'
      var propertyName = key.substr(0, key.length - key.substr(key.indexOf("["), key.length - key.indexOf("[")).length);
      if (!schema[propertyName]) {
        schema[propertyName] = [];
      }
      // schema['users'][getting index 0 from 'users[0]']
      if (!schema[propertyName][parseInt(key.substr(key.indexOf("[") + 1, key.indexOf("]") - key.indexOf("[") - 1))]) {
        // if it doesn't exist create and initialise it
        schema = schema[propertyName][parseInt(key.substr(key.indexOf("[") + 1, key.indexOf("]") - key.indexOf("[") - 1))] = {};
      } else {
        schema = schema[propertyName][parseInt(key.substr(key.indexOf("[") + 1, key.indexOf("]") - key.indexOf("[") - 1))];
      }
      continue;
    }
    if (!schema[key]) {
      schema[key] = {};
    }
    schema = schema[key];
  } //loop ends
  // if last key is array element
  if (keysList[len - 1].includes('[')) {
    //getting propertyName 'users' form key 'users[0]'
    var propertyName = keysList[len - 1].substr(0, keysList[len - 1].length - keysList[len - 1].substr(keysList[len - 1].indexOf("["), keysList[len - 1].length - keysList[len - 1].indexOf("[")).length);
    if (!schema[propertyName]) {
      schema[propertyName] = [];
    }
    // schema[users][0] = value;
    schema[propertyName][parseInt(keysList[len - 1].substr(keysList[len - 1].indexOf("[") + 1, keysList[len - 1].indexOf("]") - keysList[len - 1].indexOf("[") - 1))] = value;
  } else {
    schema[keysList[len - 1]] = value;
  }
}

// will create if not exist
set("mongo.db.users[0].name.firstname", "hii0");
set("mongo.db.users[1].name.firstname", "hii1");
set("mongo.db.users[2].name", {
  "firstname": "hii2"
});
set("mongo.db.other", "xx");
console.log(obj);

// will set if exist
set("mongo.db.other", "yy");
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to change deeper nested objects, then another method could be to reference the object. As JS objects are handled by their references, you can create a reference to an object you have string-key access to.

Example:

```
// The object we want to modify:
var obj = {
    db: {
        mongodb: {
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root'
        }
    },
    foo: {
        bar: baz
    }
};

var key1 = 'mongodb';
var key2 = 'host';

var myRef = obj.db[key1]; //this creates a reference to obj.db['mongodb']

myRef[key2] = 'my new string';

// The object now looks like:
var obj = {
    db: {
        mongodb: {
            host: 'my new string',
            user: 'root'
        }
    },
    foo: {
        bar: baz
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use recursion to dig through the object:

```js
(function(root){

  function NestedSetterAndGetter(){
    function setValueByArray(obj, parts, value){

      if(!parts){
        throw 'No parts array passed in';
      }

      if(parts.length === 0){
        throw 'parts should never have a length of 0';
      }

      if(parts.length === 1){
        obj[parts[0]] = value;
      } else {
        var next = parts.shift();

        if(!obj[next]){
          obj[next] = {};
        }
        setValueByArray(obj[next], parts, value);
      }
    }

    function getValueByArray(obj, parts, value){

      if(!parts) {
        return null;
      }

      if(parts.length === 1){
        return obj[parts[0]];
      } else {
        var next = parts.shift();

        if(!obj[next]){
          return null;
        }
        return getValueByArray(obj[next], parts, value);
      }
    }

    this.set = function(obj, path, value) {
      setValueByArray(obj, path.split('.'), value);
    };

    this.get = function(obj, path){
      return getValueByArray(obj, path.split('.'));
    };

  }
  root.NestedSetterAndGetter = NestedSetterAndGetter;

})(this);

var setter = new this.NestedSetterAndGetter();

var o = {};
setter.set(o, 'a.b.c', 'apple');
console.log(o); //=> { a: { b: { c: 'apple'}}}

var z = { a: { b: { c: { d: 'test' } } } };
setter.set(z, 'a.b.c', {dd: 'zzz'}); 

console.log(JSON.stringify(z)); //=> {"a":{"b":{"c":{"dd":"zzz"}}}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(setter.get(z, 'a.b.c'))); //=> {"dd":"zzz"}
console.log(JSON.stringify(setter.get(z, 'a.b'))); //=> {"c":{"dd":"zzz"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party - here's a vanilla js function that accepts a path as an argument and returns the modified object/json

```js
let orig_json = {
  string: "Hi",
  number: 0,
  boolean: false,
  object: {
    subString: "Hello",
    subNumber: 1,
    subBoolean: true,
    subObject: {
      subSubString: "Hello World"
    },
    subArray: ["-1", "-2", "-3"]
  },
  array: ["1", "2", "3"]
}

function changeValue(obj_path, value, json) {
  let keys = obj_path.split(".")
  let obj = { ...json },
    tmpobj = {},
    prevobj = {}
  for (let x = keys.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
    if (x == 0) {
      obj[keys[0]] = tmpobj
    } else {
      let toeval = 'json.' + keys.slice(0, x).join('.');
      prevobj = { ...tmpobj
      }
      tmpobj = eval(toeval);
      if (x == keys.length - 1) tmpobj[keys[x]] = value
      else {
        tmpobj[keys[x]] = prevobj
      }
    }
  }
  return obj
}

let newjson = changeValue("object.subObject.subSubString", "Goodbye world", orig_json);
console.log(newjson)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to add or override properties:

```js
function propertySetter(property, value) {
  const sampleObject = {
    string: "Hi",
    number: 0,
    boolean: false,
    object: {
      subString: "Hello",
      subNumber: 1,
      subBoolean: true,
      subObject: {
        subSubString: "Hello World",
      },
      subArray: ["-1", "-2", "-3"],
    },
    array: ["1", "2", "3"],
  };

  const keys = property.split(".");
  const propertyName = keys.pop();
  let propertyParent = sampleObject;
  while (keys.length > 0) {
    const key = keys.shift();
    if (!(key in propertyParent)) {
      propertyParent[key] = {};
    }
    propertyParent = propertyParent[key];
  }
  propertyParent[propertyName] = value;
  return sampleObject;
}

console.log(propertySetter("object.subObject.anotherSubString", "Hello you"));

console.log(propertySetter("object.subObject.subSubString", "Hello Earth"));

console.log(propertySetter("object.subObject.nextSubString.subSubSubString", "Helloooo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by ImmutableJS setIn method which will never mutate the original.
This works with mixed array and object nested values.

```
function setIn(obj = {}, [prop, ...rest], value) {
    const newObj = Array.isArray(obj) ? [...obj] : {...obj};
    newObj[prop] = rest.length ? setIn(obj[prop], rest, value) : value;
    return newObj;
}

var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [
        {d: 5}
      ]
    }
  }
};

const newObj = setIn(obj, ["a", "b", "c", 0, "x"], "new");

//obj === {a: {b: {c: [{d: 5}]}}}
//newObj === {a: {b: {c: [{d: 5, x: "new"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @aheuermann sed, you can use [`set` from `lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) library,

However, if you don't want to add `lodash` to your project for some reason you can use a recursion function that sets/overrides a value in an object.

```js
/**
 * recursion function that called in main function 
 * @param obj initial JSON
 * @param keysList array of keys
 * @param value value that you want to set
 * @returns final JSON
 */
function recursionSet(obj, keysList, value) {
    const key = keysList[0]
    if (keysList.length === 1) return { ...obj, [key]: value }
    return { ...obj, [key]: (recursionSet(obj?.[key] || {}, keysList.slice(1), value)) }
}

/**
 * main function that you can call for set a value in an object by nested keys
 * @param obj initial JSON
 * @param keysString nested keys that seprated by "."
 * @param value value that you want to set
 * @returns final JSON
 */
function objectSet(obj, keysString, value) {
    return recursionSet(obj, keysString.split('.'), value)
}

// simple usage
const a1 = {}
console.log('simple usage:', objectSet(a1, "b.c.d", 5))

// keep the initial data
const a2 = {b:{e: 8}}
console.log('keep the initial data:', objectSet(a2, "b.c.d", 5))

// override data
const a3 = {b:{e: 8, c:2}}
console.log('override data:', objectSet(a3, "b.c.d", 5))

// complex value
const a4 = {b:{e: 8, c:2}}
console.log('complex value:', objectSet(a4, "b.c.d", {f:12}))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like a function that required prior properties to exist, then you could use something like this, it would also return a flag stating whether it managed to find and set the nested property.

```
function set(obj, path, value) {
    var parts = (path || '').split('.');
    // using 'every' so we can return a flag stating whether we managed to set the value.
    return parts.every((p, i) => {
        if (!obj) return false; // cancel early as we havent found a nested prop.
        if (i === parts.length - 1){ // we're at the final part of the path.
            obj[parts[i]] = value;          
        }else{
            obj = obj[parts[i]]; // overwrite the functions reference of the object with the nested one.            
        }   
        return true;        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has an extend method:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

just pass the overwrites as an object and it will merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by ClojureScript's `assoc-in` (https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L5280), using recursion:

```
/**
 * Associate value (v) in object/array (m) at key/index (k).
 * If m is falsy, use new object.
 * Returns the updated object/array.
 */
function assoc(m, k, v) {
    m = (m || {});
    m[k] = v;
    return m;
}

/**
 * Associate value (v) in nested object/array (m) using sequence of keys (ks)
 * to identify the path to the nested key/index.
 * If one of the values in the nested object/array doesn't exist, it adds
 * a new object.
 */
function assoc_in(m={}, [k, ...ks], v) {
    return ks.length ? assoc(m, k, assoc_in(m[k], ks, v)) : assoc(m, k, v);
}

/**
 * Associate value (v) in nested object/array (m) using key string notation (s)
 * (e.g. "k1.k2").
 */
function set(m, s, v) {
    ks = s.split(".");
    return assoc_in(m, ks, v);
}
```

Note:

With the provided implementation,

```
assoc_in({"a": 1}, ["a", "b"], 2)
```

returns

```
{"a": 1}
```

I would prefer that it throw an error in this case. If desired, you can add a check in `assoc` to verify `m` is either an object or array and throw an error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write this **set method in short**, it may help someone!

```js
function set(obj, key, value) {
 let keys = key.split('.');
 if(keys.length<2){ obj[key] = value; return obj; }

 let lastKey = keys.pop();

 let fun = `obj.${keys.join('.')} = {${lastKey}: '${value}'};`;
 return new Function(fun)();
}

var obj = {
"hello": {
    "world": "test"
}
};

set(obj, "hello.world", 'test updated'); 
console.log(obj);

set(obj, "hello.world.again", 'hello again'); 
console.log(obj);

set(obj, "hello.world.again.onece_again", 'hello once again');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const set = (o, path, value) => {
    const props = path.split('.');
    const prop = props.shift()
    if (props.length === 0) {
        o[prop] = value
    } else {
        o[prop] = o[prop] ?? {}
        set(o[prop], props.join('.'), value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in case you want to deeply update or insert an object
try this :-

```
 let init = {
       abc: {
           c: {1: 2, 3: 5, 0: {l: 3}},
           d: 100
       }
    }
    Object.prototype.deepUpdate = function(update){
       let key = Object.keys(update);
       key.forEach((k) => {
           if(typeof update[key] == "object"){
              this[k].deepUpdate(update[key], this[k])
           }
           else 
           this[k] = update[k]
       })
    }

    init.deepUpdate({abc: {c: {l: 10}}})
    console.log(init)
```

but make sure it will change the original object, you can make it to not change the original object :

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(init)).deepUpdate({abc: {c: {l: 10}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on bpmason1's answer:
-adds a get() function.
-It does not require to define global storage object
-It is accessible from same domain iFrames

```
function set(path, value) 
{
  var schema = parent.document;
  path="data."+path;
  var pList = path.split('.');
  var len = pList.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) 
  {
    if(!schema[pList[i]]) 
      schema[pList[i]] = {}
    schema = schema[pList[i]];
  }
  schema[pList[len-1]] = value;
}

function get(path) 
{
  path="data."+path;
  var schema=parent.document;
  var pList = path.split('.');
  for(var i = 0; i < pList.length; i++) 
    schema = schema[pList[i]];
  return schema;
}

set('mongo.db.user', 'root');
set('mongo.db.name', 'glen');

console.log(get('mongo.db.name'));  //prints 'glen'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if the key also has dots (.) it its string this may pose a problem. As even that single key will now get split into various keys.

It is best to store the key path in an array, like so: ['db','mongodb','user'] and assign the value dynamically with the below function.

```js
function set(obj, path, value) {
  var schema = obj;
  var pList = path.slice();
  var len = pList.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    var elem = pList[i];
    if (!schema[elem]) schema[elem] = {};
    schema = schema[elem];
  }
  schema[pList[len - 1]] = value;
}
    
let path = ['db','mongodb','user'];
set(obj, path, 'root');
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave my answer for this interesting topic. Creating a function that sets dynamic properties for an object can be difficult.

```js
const entity = {
  haveDogs: true,
  dogs: ['Maya', 'Perla']
}

function isObject(obj) {
  return obj instanceof Object && obj.constructor === Object;
}

function setSchema(key, schema, value) {
  if (!isObject(value)) {
    schema[key] = value;
    return
  }
      
  if (!schema[key]) schema[key] = {}
  schema[key] = mutate(schema[key], value);
}

function mutate(obj, newObjData) {
    const keys = Object.keys(newObjData)
    
    for (const key of keys) {
      let schema = obj
      const list = key.split('.')
      const value = newObjData[key]
      const total = list.length - 1
      
      if (list.length === 1) {
        setSchema(key, schema, value)
        continue
      }
      
      for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        const elem = list[i];
        if (!schema[elem]) schema[elem] = {}
        schema = schema[elem]
      }
      
      const subField = list[total]
      setSchema(subField, schema, value)
    }

    return obj
}

mutate(entity, {
  haveDogs: false,
  'pet1.pet2.pet3.pet4.pet5': 'pets',
  'bestFriends.list': ['Maya', 'Lucas'],
  friends: {
    'whitelist.permitted': ['Maya', 'Perla'], 
    'party.blocked': ['Juan', 'Trump']
  }
})

console.log('[entity]', entity)
```