# Convert JS single-line object instantiation to block instantiation

Tags: javascript, text-parsing

I have user-specified input that looks like this:

```
outerObject = {};
outerObject.innerObject = {};
outerObject.innerObject.key = 'value';
outerObject.innerObject.exampleTwo = 2;
```

Repeat that general pattern for a couple thousand lines, and you see how this looks a little tedious and is hard to maintain. What I'd like to do is output these lines into something like this:

```
outerObject = {
    innerObject: {
        key: 'value',
        exampleTwo: 2
    }
};
```

Is there an existing library to convert the single-line object creations into the block creation shown above? And if not, mind taking a stab at code that could? I'm so fundamentally confused at where to start that I can't even figure out how to nest objects, so any help would be great.

EDIT: I stumbled upon [this accepted answer for a different issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937118/3352692). It appears to format an object the way I want after splitting the value and key from each of the four lines in that first block. It does not include any sort of output formatting, however...

Comment: I don't understand the question; are you trying to manipulate _text that looks like JavaScript_?

Comment: That's correct. I'm taking existing JavaScript text and trying to format it into what appears to be equivalent text, just using object notation.

Comment: You could just get the outerObject in the browser console (if it all just JSON-like static content in that object, that is)

Comment: What format is the user-specified input in? Is it actually JavaScript, or something else? If it’s actually JavaScript, use a JavaScript parser – https://github.com/ternjs/acorn, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

> This method only works when all objects are static/JSON-like, meaning
>   no functions or anything

You could just evaluate your input like this in the browser (or the browser console or any js context, like Node):

```
<script>
    outerObject = {};
    outerObject.innerObject = {};
    outerObject.innerObject.key = 'value';
    outerObject.innerObject.exampleTwo = 2;
</script>
```

Then just `JSON.stringify(outerObject, null, '    ')` which will return

```
"{
    "innerObject": {
        "key": "value",
        "exampleTwo": 2
    }
}"
```

All you do next is append `"outerObject = "` in front