# How do pointers work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, pointers

I [stumbled upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936915/dynamically-set-property-of-nested-object) the following code:

```
obj = {};  // global object

function set(path, value) {
    var schema = obj;  // a moving reference to internal objects within obj
    var pList = path.split('.');
    var len = pList.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
        var elem = pList[i];
        if( !schema[elem] ) schema[elem] = {}
        schema = schema[elem];
    }

    schema[pList[len-1]] = value;
}

set('mongo.db.user', 'root');
```

I read a bit further on it and found that `schema` is acting as a pointer of `obj`. How does this work? I even re-wrote the above code to incorporate ES6:

```js
console.log(set('mongo.db.user', 'root'));

function set(path, data = '', obj = {}, delim = '.') {
  if (path) {;
    path.split(delim).reduce((s, n, i, a) => {
      s.pointer[n] = s.pointer[n] || i === a.length - 1 ? data : {};
      s.pointer = s.pointer[n];
      return s;
    }, {pointer: obj});
  }
  return obj;
}
```

However I feel limited in my ability to expand upon this because I do not see how, for example, if `pointer` is `obj`, how does setting `s.pointer[n]` set object, but `s.pointer = s.pointer[n]` not set/overwrite `obj`?

If someone could please explain this that would be great - also if I am missing something from the bigger picture (and thus didn't ask) please let me know.

Comment: There are no pointers. So "pointers don't work" in ECMAScript. The "secret" is this: 1) *an object is **always** itself* (so anything that modifies the object .. modifies the object), and 2) *assignment and parameter passing **never** copies/clones objects* (so an assigned/passed object is .. the same object)

Comment: (Unfortunately people like to bring in concepts like 'references' from *other* languages; these are not required to understand the simple-once-you-know-the-two-rules behavior. Although, Jon Skeet [??] had a good House Address analogy somewhere..)

Comment: I think one final thing to help reduce confusion is to consider variables are simply *names* for objects, and an object (like a person) may be known by one *or more* names. Thus, a variable in JavaScript does *not* "store a reference" (again, there are no 'references' from other mainstream languages present in JS), but rather, "a variable *names* an object" or - by English equivalence of terms - "a variable *refers to* an object".

Comment: Java seems to have been one of the main perpetrators at leaking implementation.. but ECMAScript/JavaScript != Java.

Comment: I disagree to the comments above. Yes, the term "pointers" was not coined in JS, instead its called a "reference", but thats exactly what the OP describes here, so the question is actually "How do references work in JS"?

Comment: That said, I think you will find a lot of great explanations under the term "call by sharing", but this still remains a great question, so if there is a something in the duplicate that you don't understand I will be glad to reopen / answer / help :)