# Writing generic React input hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to write a generic React Hook to allow me to update objects.

I took reference from: Input Hook - (source: https://rangle.io/blog/simplifying-controlled-inputs-with-hooks/) and made some changes:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useForm = initialObject => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialObject);

  return {
    values: values || initialObject,
    setValues,
    reset: () => setValues({}),
    bind: {
      onChange: (event) => {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        })
      }
    }
  };
};
```

This worked well from single level objects:

```
{ name: '', type: '' }
```

but for objects with nested values:

```
{ name: '', type: '', price: { dollar: 5, cents: 20  } }
```

I'm too sure how I should replace `[event.target.id]` to read nested level objects.

Could someone advise?

**Updated:**

```
import { useState } from "react";

export const useForm = initialObject => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialObject);

  return {
    values: values || initialObject,
    setValues,
    reset: () => setValues({}),
    bind: {
      onChange: (event) => {
        // ###need make this part generic###
        // event.target.id will be "price.dollar"
        values['price']['dollar'] = event.target.value;
        setValues({
          ...values
        })
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally your hook should accept a `name` and `value` to update your local state. Apparently your hook always receive an `event` and you extract the `event.target.id` as the `name` of the field and `event.target.value` as the value of the field. I would suggest you to update your hook to receive a `name` and a `value` as argument instead, and letting the component that uses the hook to define what is `name` and `value`

Based on your hook, you can update nested object like this. Please take a look at this example.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const useForm = initialObject => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialObject);

  return {
    values: values || initialObject,
    setValues,
    reset: () => setValues({}),
    bind: {
      onChange: event => {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
      }
    }
  };
};

const App = () => {
  const { values, bind } = useForm({
    name: "",
    type: "",
    price: { dollar: 5, cents: 20 }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      Hook state:
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)}</pre>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Name : <br />
            <input id="name" onChange={bind.onChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Type : <br />
            <input id="type" onChange={bind.onChange} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Price - Dollar : <br />
            <input
              id="dollar"
              type="number"
              onChange={e => {
                bind.onChange({
                  target: {
                    id: "price",
                    value: { ...values.price, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Price - Cents : <br />
            <input
              id="cents"
              type="number"
              onChange={e => {
                bind.onChange({
                  target: {
                    id: "price",
                    value: { ...values.price, [e.target.id]: e.target.value }
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

### Update (11/25/2019):

You can, however, update your hook as the following

```
const useForm = initialObject => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialObject);

  return {
    values: values || initialObject,
    setValues,
    reset: () => setValues({}),
    bind: {
      onChange: event => {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
      },
      onNestedChange: (event, name) => {
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [name]: {
            ...values[name],
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value,
          }
        })
      }
    }
  };
};
```

Then in your inputs, you can write as the following:

```
<div>
  <label>
    Price - Dollar : <br />
    <input
      id="dollar"
      type="number"
      onChange={e => bind.onNestedChange(e, 'price')}
    />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Price - Cents : <br />
    <input
      id="cents"
      type="number"
      onChange={e => bind.onNestedChange(e, 'price')}
    />
  </label>
</div>
```

That way you created another bind method for nested object, and perhaps you can add another called `array` or something. Hope that this gives you some idea on how to improve the hook. By the way there are **plenty** of way to do this, this is just an example. There are probably better ways of doing this.

### Update 2 (11/25/2019):

I've updated your `useForm` hook, now you can set nested object property to your state. However, I've not tested with array and it will probably cause issue.

```
const useForm = initialObject => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialObject);
  // Copied and modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937118/11125492
  const nestedObjectSet = (obj, path, value) => {
    let schema = obj; // a moving reference to internal objects within obj
    const pList = path.split(".");
    const len = pList.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
      let elem = pList[i];
      if (!schema[elem]) schema[elem] = {};
      schema = schema[elem];
    }
    schema[pList[len - 1]] = value;
  };
  // handleOnChange update state value
  const handleOnChange = event => {
    let newValues = Object.assign({}, values);
    nestedObjectSet(newValues, event.target.name, event.target.value);
    setValues(newValues);
  };
  return {
    values: values || initialObject,
    setValues,
    reset: () => setValues({}),
    bind: {
      onChange: handleOnChange
    }
  };
};
```

You can use it like that. Notice that I've changed the `key` of the object to take from `event.target.id` to `event.target.name`. The `key` should be set in `name` instead of `id`

```
const App = () => {
  const { values, bind } = useForm({
    name: "",
    type: "",
    price: { dollar: 5, cents: 20 }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      Hook state:
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)}</pre>
      <div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Name : <br />
            <input name="name" {...bind} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Type : <br />
            <input name="type" {...bind} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Price - Dollar : <br />
            <input name="price.dollar" type="number" {...bind} />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            Price - Cents : <br />
            <input name="price.cents" type="number" {...bind} />
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Sandbox Demo Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-useform-hook-nested-object-cqn9j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks @dev_junwen, I get your approach.. But there are many fields in the object and I am hoping to write a generic approach where the onChange is binded by the hook and than on individual element. Do you know how can I tweak the approach?

Comment: thanks for the update.. I updated the question with a closer example to what I was hoping for.. Ideally, not having to bind each component separately. Would be great if you can help take a look again.

Comment: Thanks @dev_junwen for your help. Yeah I went with a similar approach in the end!