# AngularJS / Javascript - How to update any value in a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have an object in AngularJS which stores my user data (called $scope.userData). The object looks something like this :

- user

  - user_profile
- content
- sharing_data

  - pages
  - follows
  - subscriptions

with each of those bullet points storing an array of vars. I would like to write a function to update any var stored within, for example I would like to update userData.sharing_data.pages[0], or delete userData.content[2], or add a value such userData.user.user_profile.profile_pic_url = 'myUrl';

How can I find and update any value in a nested object like this, without overwriting the whole object?

Comment: what have you tried so far? actually doing `userData.user.user_profile.profile_pic_url = 'myUrl'` won't overwrite the whole object

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936915/dynamically-set-property-of-nested-object.

Comment: I think this is angular framework related, you might get a better answer if you add this tag as this framework have a different way of watching value changes than plain javascript