# Is there a simpler way to replace nested property?

Tags: javascript, testing, task

During an interview I've got interesting javascript-task:

> Given the code:
>
> ```js
> const testStr = "bar.baz.foo:111222",
>       testObj = {
>         bar: {
>           baz: {
>             foo: 333444,
>             foo2: 674654
>           },
>           boo: {
>             faa: 11
>           }
>         },
>         fee: 333
>       };
>
> function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
>   // your code
> }
> ```
>
> write the implementation of the `replaceInObj` function

1. I was not allowed to use 3rd-party library.
2. I kinda solved the task, but I'm not satisfied with my solution.
3. And I'm struggling with my complex implementation.
4. At the same time I cannot find another solution by myself.

### My implementation of the `replaceInObj` function

```js
const testStr = 'bar.baz.foo:111222';
const testObj = {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      foo: 333444,
      foo2: 674654,
    },
    boo: {
      faa: 11,
    },
  },
  fee: 333,
};

console.log('[before] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

// run
replaceInObj(testObj, testStr);

console.log('[after] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  const [path, valueToChange] = str.split(':');

  path.split('.').reduce((acc, prop, index, arr) => {
    const isLastProp = arr.length === index + 1;
    if (isLastProp) {
      acc[prop] = valueToChange;
    }

    return acc[prop];
  }, obj);
}
```

### How would you implement the function `replaceInObj`?

- I hope there's much-much simpler implementation.
- And I would be grateful if you'd share your solution

Comment: Questions on improving working code in terms of best practice, efficiency, readability, ... are better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). How anyone would *want* to do it, is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Didn't know that such an platform even existed - gonna post it to code-review then!

Comment: "*How would you implement the function?*" - a bit of searching around with the right keywords will find you thousands of alternative solution for this quite common task, including [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18936915/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found solution much cleaner and simpler to understand:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/240907/227075

### That solution adjusted to my task

```js
const testStr = 'bar.baz.foo:111222';
const testObj = {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      foo: '333444',
    },
  },
};

console.log('[before] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

// run
replaceInObj(testObj, testStr);

console.log('[after] testObj.bar.baz =', testObj.bar.baz);

function replaceInObj(obj, str) {
  const [path, valueToChange] = str.split(':');
  const properties = path.split('.');
  const lastProperty = properties.pop();
  const lastObject = properties.reduce((a, prop) => a[prop], obj);
  lastObject[lastProperty] = valueToChange;
}
```