# How to update nested keys when you have keys in array javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a requirement wherein I get nested object keys in an array. I have an array of keys like

```
let keys = ["vehicleInformation", "VehicleBlock|1", "DriverAssociation|1", "DriverInvolvedAssociation"]
```

There is already a JSON data that is stored in a variable and I have to update a data object.

```
data['vehicleInformation']['VehicleBlock'][1]['DriverAssociation'][1]['DriverInvolvedAssociation'] = value;
```

Is there a way to achieve this in javascript?
Initial value of data:

data = {};

Expected result:

```
data = {
  vehicleInformation: {
    VehicleBlock: [
      {},
      {
        DriverAssociation: [
          {},
          {DriverInvolvedAssociation: value},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Your description was pretty minimal, but if what you're interested in is changing a variable nested deep in an object, this looks pretty handy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50392139/1772933

Answer (score 1):

```js
keys = ["vehicleInformation", "VehicleBlock|1", "DriverAssociation|1", "DriverInvolvedAssociation"]
data = {
  vehicleInformation: {
    VehicleBlock: [
      0,
      {
        DriverAssociation: [
          0,
          {},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

let value = 42;
let keysToLast = keys.flatMap(key => key.split("|"));
let lastKey = keysToLast.pop();
keysToLast.reduce((a, e) => a[e], data)[lastKey] = value;
console.log(data);
```

Array keys are just strings like object keys, no reason to treat them differently (thus `flatMap`). Then just `reduce` to find the object whose property you need to set, and set it.

Comment: why to use `flatMap` then finding the `lastKey` and then `reduce`. When you can do exactly same with `reduce`. CODE =>>  `keys.reduce((acc, curr, index, arr) => {
  const [key, i] = curr.split("|");
  if (index === arr.length - 1) return (acc[key] = value);
  if (!i) {
    acc = acc[key];
  } else {
    acc = acc[key][i];
  }
  console.log(acc);
  return acc;
}, data);`

Comment: @decpk Sure, you can, but I feel my way to be more general (and `flatMap` only serves to satisfy the OP's artificial separation of array and object keys, and prepare for the general operation of digging into a data structure). The same logic for taking the last key out - the operation of digging to the next-to-last key for writing and digging to the last key for reading are completely equivalent.