# How to perform deep optional assignment in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, null, optional-chaining

Say I have an object named `foo`, and I would like to perform the following operation:

`foo.bar.baz.qwer.asdf = 5;`

The issue is that `bar` may not exist, but if it does exist, then `baz` inside of it may not exist, etc.

I thought I would be able to do something like this:

`foo?.bar?.baz?.qwer?.asdf = 5`, but alas, that sort of chaining only seems to work with retrieving values, not setting values.

The desired behavior is that if something like `baz` already exists, then that object is just accessed (and its existing members are maintained), but if `baz` does not exist, then that property is created on the fly.

That is, let's say only `foo.bar` existed. Then after the above assignment operation, the resulting object would be:

```
foo {
  bar: {
    baz: {
      qwer: {
        asdf: 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is: can this be done with existing language syntax constructs, or must a helper function be created? If so, does this sort of function have a name that I could search for and reference?

Comment: I think you have too check if each property exists unless you want to overwrite them.

Comment: @about14sheep Yeah, that would work, but it would be too cumbersome, verbose, and error-prone in this case, as I have very deep objects, and need to perform this sort of operation in many different places.

Comment: so if `bar` exists, do you not want to keep iterating until you get too `asdf`? Or are you only concerned with the final property in the chain existing?

Comment: This is how PHP array assignment works, but you'd have to roll your own function to make it work in Javascript.

Comment: @about14sheep The latter. The final property must be made, and any intermediate objects along the way should be constructed if necessary.

Comment: @TKoL Ah, very well. I'll begin work on writing such a function now, and if no one else replies with an answer, I'll answer this question with what I come up with (if I figure it out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written this:

```js
function setProperty(obj, property, value) {
    const properties = property.split('.');
    const lastProperty = properties.pop();
    for (let prop of properties) {
        if (!obj[prop]) {
            obj[prop] = {};
        }
        obj = obj[prop];
    }
    obj[lastProperty] = value;
}

const startObj = {'a': {}};

setProperty(startObj, 'a.b.c.d.e', 'e is the best letter');
console.log(startObj);
```

However, it will have unexpected behaviors if one of the intermediate properties exists but isn't an object. Eg test the above function with the starting object `{a:{b:2}}`

Also, please note that what `obj` means changes as the function processes. At first, it means the base object, but it goes on to mean each nested object during the loop.

Comment: Thanks, this function looks good, and that unexpected behavior _should_ be fine, I think, as that would just be a bug with the application anyway, which should cause a crash and investigation. Thanks.

Comment: I found a guy that gave functionally equivalent code to a similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936915/dynamically-set-property-of-nested-object

Comment: Ah, there it is. I was looking for that thread but my Googlefu was failing me. Good find

Comment: I think my code is better though ;)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Also, lodash seems to have a `set` function, which I may use, since this project has already imported lodash anyway. Anyways, thanks again!