# Updating nested object by path in javascript

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Let's say I have this object:

```
{
  categories: [
     { name: "My Category", products: [ { name: "My Product", price: 15 }] },
     { name: "Another", products: [ { name: "Movie", price: 25 }, { name: "Cartoon", price: 7.5 } ] },
     { name: "Lastly", subcategories: [ 
            { name: "Food", products: [ { name: "Avocado", price: 1.25} ] }
         ] 
     }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to update the price in this object through a function call as follows:

```
update(object, "categories/0/products/0",25) 
// this would change first product in first category
```

This answer [Javascript: how to dynamically create nested objects using object names given by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484673/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-using-object-names-given-by) is good but does not address the case when there are arrays in the object.

Underscore acceptable.

Note: this answer [Javascript: how to dynamically create nested objects INCLUDING ARRAYS using object names given by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856318/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-including-arrays-using-obje?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not cut it because I don't have array references in that form (products[1])

Comment: How is the string generated? This could be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Just finding out I might be better off using json patch. Still researching.

Comment: All depends on higher level use case which hasn't been defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly modify function from the linked answer

```js
var object = {
  categories: [
     { name: "My Category", products: [ { name: "My Product", price: 15 }] },
     { name: "Another", products: [ { name: "Movie", price: 25 }, { name: "Cartoon", price: 7.5 } ] },
     { name: "Lastly", subcategories: [ 
            { name: "Food", products: [ { name: "Avocado", price: 1.25} ] }
         ] 
     }
  ]
}

function update(obj, keyPath, value) {
   keyPath = keyPath.split('/');  // split key path string
   lastKeyIndex = keyPath.length-1;
   for (var i = 0; i < lastKeyIndex; ++ i) {
     key = keyPath[i];
     
     // choose if nested object is array or hash based on if key is number
     if (!(key in obj)) obj[key] = parseInt(key) !== parseInt(key) ? {}: []
     obj = obj[key];
   }
   obj[keyPath[lastKeyIndex]] = value;
}

console.log(`Original price ${object.categories[0].products[0].price}`);
update(object, "categories/0/products/0/price",25)
console.log(`New price ${object.categories[0].products[0].price}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this, maybe it can help.

```js
const updateObjectValueByPath = ({ arrayPath, data, value }) => {
  const key = arrayPath[0];

  if (Array.isArray(data) && data !== null) {
    if (arrayPath.length > 1) {
      return data.map((el, index) => {
        if (index === key) {
          return updateObjectValueByPath({
            arrayPath: arrayPath.slice(1, arrayPath.length),
            data: el,
            value,
          });
        }

        return el;
      }, []);
    }

    return [...data, value];
  }

  if (typeof data === 'object' && !Array.isArray(data) && data !== null) {
    if (arrayPath.length > 1) {
      return {
        ...data,
        [key]: updateObjectValueByPath({
          arrayPath: arrayPath.slice(1, arrayPath.length),
          data: data[key],
          value,
        }),
      };
    }

    return { ...data, [key]: value };
  }

  return data;
};

const data = {
  categories: [
     { name: "My Category", products: [ { name: "My Product", price: 15 }] },
     { name: "Another", products: [ { name: "Movie", price: 25 }, { name: "Cartoon", price: 7.5 } ] },
     { name: "Lastly", subcategories: [ 
            { name: "Food", products: [ { name: "Avocado", price: 1.25} ] }
         ] 
     }
  ]
};

const arrayPath = ['categories', 0, 'products', 0, 'price'];
const value = 25;

const newData = updateObjectValueByPath({data, value, arrayPath});
console.log({newData});
```