# Javascript - Parsing INI file into nested associative array

Tags: javascript, associative-array, nest-nested-object

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having trouble parsing an INI formatted file into nested objects.

The file I have is formatted like this:

```
ford.car.focus.transmission=standard
ford.car.focus.engine=four-cylinder
ford.car.focus.fuel=gas

ford.car.taurus.transmission=automatic
ford.car.taurus.engine=V-8
ford.car.taurus.fuel=diesel

purchased=Ford Taurus
```

I would like to have the structure look like this:

```
{ ford:
  { car:
    { focus:
      {
        transmission: 'standard',
        engine: 'four-cylinder',
        fuel: 'gas'
      }
    }
    { taurus:
      {
        transmission: 'automatic',
        engine: 'V-8',
        fuel: 'diesel'
      }
    }
  }
  purchased: 'Ford Taurus'
}
```

I'm storing the file in lines in an array, splitting on '\n'. I'm trying to write a method that would be called in a loop, passing my global object like this:

```
var hash = {};
var array = fileData.toString().split("\n");
for (i in array) {
  var tmp = array[i].split("=");
  createNestedObjects(tmp[0], tmp[1], hash);
}
```

This should let me access the values in the hash object like:

```
hash.ford.car.focus.fuel
# 'gas'

hash.purchase
# 'Ford Taurus'
```

I've tried something like what was suggested here: [Javascript: how to dynamically create nested objects using object names given by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484673/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-using-object-names-given-by), but it only seems to set the last item in the nest.

```
{ fuel: 'diesel',
  purchased: 'Ford Taurus' }
```

My unsuccessful attempt looks like this:

```
createNestedObjects(path, value, obj) {
  var keys = path.split('.');
  keys.reduce(function(o, k) {
    if (k == keys[keys.length-1]) {
      return o[k] = value;
    } else {
      return o[k] = {};
    }
  }, obj);
}
```

However, it will only return the last value for the nested values:

```
{ ford: { car: { taurus: { fuel: 'diesel' } } },
  purchased: 'Ford Taurus' }
```

Comment: `createNestedObjects` doesn't check whether the key already exists in the object, so it replaces it if it already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function needs to check whether an intermediate key already exists before assigning to it.

```
createNestedObjects(path, value, obj) {
  var keys = path.split('.');
  keys.reduce(function(o, k) {
    if (k == keys[keys.length-1]) {
      return o[k] = value;
    } else if (o[k]) {
      return o[k];
    } else {
      return o[k] = {};
    }
  }, obj);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!