# Adding key-value pair to javascript object where key is an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

1) I am trying to add a sequence of key-value pairs to a JS plain object, where the key itself is an object. Each time I add a key-value pair, the object is overwritten (see live [here](http://jsbin.com/dojapegozo/edit?html,js,console,output)).

```
var x = {};

var y = {
  'name': 'cat',
  'note': 'lazy animal'
}
var yy = 'meow'

x[{
  'name': 'dog',
  'note': 'loyal animal'
}] = 'bhow'
x[y] = yy

for(var k in x) {
  console.log(k);
  console.log(x[k]);
}
```

Console Output:

```
"[object Object]"
"meow"
```

2) This (overwriting behavior) does not happen when the key is a string (see live [here](http://jsbin.com/sobiyeheje/edit?html,js,console,output)).

```
var x = {};

var y = 'cat'
var yy = 'meow'

x['dog'] = 'bhow'
x[y] = yy

for(var k in x) {
  console.log(k);
  console.log(x[k]);
}
```

Console Output:

```
"dog"
"bhow"
"cat"
"meow"
```

Would like to understand why this is happening?

I figured our some solutions by going through the other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484673/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-using-object-names-given-by)). But I am unable to grasp the concept here. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't. Object keys can only be strings or symbols. You want a Map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Object keys should be strings. Moreover, you are not specifying the same keys in the second example, so obviously there won't be any overwriting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object keys have to be strings (or symbols), so when you try to use an object as a key, it first converts it to a string representation, which you've seen is `"[object Object]"`.

You *can* however do what you wish to do by overriding the `toString` function on your objects, and as long as you return a unique string for each object (perhaps as a hash of the object's contents), your code will work as expected, as it will use that `toString` function to obtain the string representation of your object, and use that as the key:

```js
var x = {};

var y = {
  'name': 'cat',
  'note': 'lazy animal',
  toString: function() {
    return 'yobj';
  }
};
var yy = 'meow';

x[{
  'name': 'dog',
  'note': 'loyal animal',
  toString: function() {
    return 'xobj';
  }
}] = 'bhow';
x[y] = yy;

for (var k in x) {
  console.log(k);
  console.log(x[k]);
}
```

---

As Jared mentions in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816752/adding-key-value-pair-to-javascript-object-where-key-is-an-object/37816983#comment63098008_37816752), the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object (introduced with ES6 last year) is in part designed to solve this problem, and allows you to use objects directly as your keys if you're running in an [environment that supports its use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

Any time you pass something to the property accessor of an object (the `object[...]` syntax), it gets converted to a string (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) under "Property names").

Plain Javascript objects like those you're using are typecasted to strings using [the default `toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method which simply returns `"[object Object]"`. That's why they both end up pointing to the same value.