# Defining a nested object property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I need to send a JSON object to a server which requires that the properties 
are nested. For example, the data object may be nested 2 levels deep. However, one cannot simply declare the object directly:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar.bartwo = "data"; //Uncaught TypeError
```

I am currently attempting to bypass this by manually creating the nested object layer.

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = {};
foo.bar.bartwo = "data"; //Successful
```

However, this can quickly get out of hand if the object requires multiple levels of nesting.

Is there a better method in Javascript or Jquery to handle this issue (which does not work by simply golfing the second code example)?

Clarification: The solution should be able to allow for direct access to nested properties, *without* necessitating that all of the intermediate properties also be created.

Comment: `var foo = {bar: {bartwo: "data"}};`

Comment: create simple "namespace" function. or google one

Comment: @naththedeveloper While your solution is more concise, it doesn't actually solve the root problem. The nesting may require multiple levels to be generated dynamically, which would not work with your example.

Comment: What you're asking is impossible because to add a property to an object, the object must exist. The best you can do is make a function that lessens the burden of doing so, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433067/5743988).

Comment: var foo['bar'] = {'a': 'b'} You can do something like this

Answer (score 0):

without defining nested object i.e foo.bar = {};
you can not use or assign value to it
javascript object must be defined first to use it
otherwise it will give you 'undefined' error i.e foo.bar is undefined

Answer (score 0):

create a small method that does this

```
function nested(x, y){
nestedA="";
parts = x.split('.');
  for(i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    nestedA += parts[i];
    eval(nestedA + ' = {}');
    nestedA += '.';
}
eval(nestedA.slice(0,-1)+ '= "'+y+'"');
}
nested('foo.bar.bartwo', "data");
```

Comment: Test your code. There are several syntax issues with it.

Comment: What is `.=` doing? Is it concatenation?

Comment: adding to the string

Comment: Concatenation is JS would be `+=`, but then you're overwriting the value with `{}` anyway. Run your code please.

Comment: thanks i missed that

Comment: ok tested now working as should

Comment: It's still just returning a string. It's not doing anything more than returning `x`

Comment: yeh sorry am just a NOOB learning through ansewering

Comment: now does exactly what he asked

Comment: Look at [the answer in the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11433067/5743988). You will find a much nicer algorithm. (Btw, using `eval` is a bad habit. There are only a few specific times when it is appropriate to use it)