# Need code explanation(how it work and why)

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to understand the below code and how it's actually working.

```
var createNestedObject = function( base, names ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++ ) {
        base = base[ names[i] ] = base[ names[i] ] || {};
    }
};

// Usage:
createNestedObject( window, ["shapes", "triangle", "points"] );
// Now window.shapes.triangle.points is an empty object, ready to be used.
```

It's from this Q/A:
[Javascript: how to dynamically create nested objects using object names given by an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484673/javascript-how-to-dynamically-create-nested-objects-using-object-names-given-by)

Can you please explain how the `base = base[ names[i] ] = base[ names[i] ] || {};` works?

My thought process stuck and broken because of the above code. Drives me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please explain how the `base = base[ names[i] ] = base[ names[i] ] || {}`; works?

Let's assume we're on the first turn of the loop, and so `base` is `window`, `i` is `0` and `names[i]` is "shapes". The first part to evaluate is `base[ names[i] ] || {}`. This is going to resolve to `window.shapes` if it exists, or an empty object if it does not.

Next, we move left to this assignment:

```
base[ names[i] ] = base[ names[i] ] || {};
```

That's going to assign to `window.shapes` whatever we got from the right hand side. So if `window.shapes` already exists, we assign it to itself and nothing changes. Or if it doesn't exist, we assign an empty object to it.

And moving left one more time:

```
base = base[ names[i] ] = base[ names[i] ] || {};
```

We now are going to reassign the `base` variable to point to the object we just created (or the object we reused). So for the next turn of the loop, `base` is no longer `window`, it's `window.shapes`.

At this point the loop repeats, but our variables are now one step farther along. `base` is `window.shapes`, `i` is `1`, and `names[i]` is "triangles". Since `base` is now `window.shapes`, we're probing and assigning to an object that's one layer deeper. So while the first time through the loop we made sure `window.shapes` existed, this time we're checking if `window.shapes.triangle` exists. And so it will continue, deeper and deeper into the object with each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code is doing several – maybe too much – things at a time. One way to understand it is to take the things apart and have  separate steps:

```
// Original line
base = base[ names[i] ] = base[names[i]] || {};

// Add parentheses according to JavaScript operator preferences
base = base[ names[i] ] = ( base[names[i]] || {} );

// Separate the two assignments
base[ names[i] ] = base[names[i]] || {};
base = base[ names[i] ];

// Replace the use of || as null coalescing operator with the ?: operator
base[ names[i] ] = base[names[i]] ? base[names[i]] : {};
base = base[ names[i] ];

// Replace the ?: operator with if-else
if (base[names[i]]) {
  base[names[i]] = base[names[i]]
} else {
  base[names[i]] = {}
}
base = base[ names[i] ];

// Swap if and else branches
if (!base[names[i]]) {
  base[names[i]] = {}
} else {
  base[names[i]] = base[names[i]]
}
base = base[ names[i] ];

// Get rid of the else branch as it is not doing anything
if (!base[names[i]]) {
  base[names[i]] = {}
}
base = base[ names[i] ];
```

Comment: So, for the first iteration it would be:
`if (!window.shapes) {
  window.shapes = {}
}
window = window.shapes;`

For the second one:
if (!window.triangle) {
  window.triangle = {}
}
window = window.triangle;`

Can you please explain why it doesn't end up in a form of `window: { shapes: {}, triangle: {}, points: {} }`?

Comment: I got it, thank you for you help!

Comment: It does end up in the correct form – nested: "window": { "shapes": { "triangle": { "points": {} } } }